# Mesh not tracking properly/only rotates 180 degrees using bones (2.9.3)

Tags: armature

I've been working on rigging, and I've been having some problems I can't figure out for the life of me.[image: normal state] [image: moving bones][image: rotation][image: more rotation]

Comment: can u provide blend file pls?

Comment: it's a sensitive file, although I can strip out some irrelevant parts if that works

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Odds are good that the mesh is not fully weighted.  If you think that it is fully weighted, it is probably the case that it is also weighted to some other bone, making it not fully weighted, since weights are **relative** weights of bone influence.